# Proper way to define a namespaced model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

Just wondering what is the proper way to define a namespaced model in Rails. I've seen it defined in two ways. In most libraries they seem to be defined as such

```
module Fruit
  class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
  end
end
```

whereas the Rails generator seems to prefer this

```
class Fruit::Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

They both obviously work but what is the difference? Which is preferred? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are identical, second is just syntax sugar.

Comment: This is not true. I've added an answer explaining myself.

Answer (score 1):

They are not identical, the more verbose way will actually define the module, whereas the shorter way will expect it to be defined already.

```
class Fruit::Banana; end
```

That will throw a `NameError`. However if you do

```
module Fruit; end
class Fruit::Banana; end
```

it will not throw an error.

Comment: Wow you're right. `irb(main):002:0> class Fruit::Banana; end`
`NameError: uninitialized constant Fruit`

Answer (score 0):

They're the same, but the "longer" version lets you add other stuff to the module. *I* prefer that since I'll often package multiple small things into a module that way.